# The xml corrupt my Base 64 string when i set it as attribute in flex

Tags: xml, apache-flex, air, flash-builder

I convert an image byte array into `base64` string, it successfully converted and if i convert it back into byte array and assign to any image as source work fine.

The Problem,

If i try to set the same `base64` string as an attribute of an XML that i am locally created for saving purpose it disturb or corrupt my base64 string before send to server.

any help ?

```
var ImageBase64String    :String;
ImageBase64String     = AppUtils.getBase64String(m_oImageContent);
var UpdateUserXML:XML = <UpdateUser />;
UpdateUserXML.@ImageData        = ImageBase64String; 
trace(UpdateUserXML.toString());
```

Comment: Details please? How is it corrupted? How do you know it is corrupted?

Comment: and also, code how you store your XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this in this way,

```
public static function getCDATANode(data:String, tagName:String):void
{
        var node:XML  = new XML(  "<" + tagName + "/>" );
        var cdata:XML = new XML("<![CDATA[" + data + " ]]>");
        node.appendChild(cdata);

        trace("getCDATANode: ", node.toXMLString() );
}
```